# Leaking file descriptors

Tags: shell, lvm

What does it mean if file descriptor leaking

```
 File descriptor 6 (socket:[901758]) leaked on lvextend invocation. Parent PID 10035: /bin/zsh
 File descriptor 9 (/dev/pts/1) leaked on lvextend invocation. Parent PID 10035: /bin/zsh
 File descriptor 11 (/dev/pts/1) leaked on lvextend invocation. Parent PID 10035: /bin/zsh
 File descriptor 12 (/dev/pts/1) leaked on lvextend invocation. Parent PID 10035: /bin/zsh
 File descriptor 15 (/dev/pts/7) leaked on lvextend invocation. Parent PID 10035: /bin/zsh
 File descriptor 17 (/dev/pts/7) leaked on lvextend invocation. Parent PID 10035: /bin/zsh
 File descriptor 18 (/dev/pts/7) leaked on lvextend invocation. Parent PID 10035: /bin/zsh
   Extending logical volume usr to 30.00 GiB
   Logical volume usr successfully resized
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are file descriptors left open on the device (which you were resizing).

lvm(8) says:

```
On invocation, lvm requires that only the standard file descriptors stdin, stdout
and stderr are available. If others are found, they get closed and messages
are issued warning about the leak.
```

Comment: No, not quite. These are open file descriptors passed to the `lvm` command; for some reason someone decided to be helpful here.

Comment: To anyone that is searching how to suppress this messages

`This warning can be suppressed by setting the environment variable LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS`

Comment: I do not understand why the answer is incorrect.  Normally, a filesystem is passed to lvm commands, not files...

Comment: as edoput said: `export LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS=1`